# Is it true that whenever $\forall a\forall b(a\leq b\implies f(a)\leq f(b))$ is true, then $\forall a\forall b(f(a)<f(b)\implies a<b)$ is also true?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

The universe is the set of real numbers.

I thought of this when learning about monotonic functions and their how their inverse is also monotonic. I can't find a counter-example, which leads me to believe that the statement is true; but how do I go about proving it?

Another way to look at the problem is the following; knowing that $\forall a\forall b(a\leq b\implies f(a)\leq f(b))$, how can I prove that $\forall a\forall b(a\geq b\implies f(a)\geq f(b))$?

Comment: the inverse is also monotonic, so you take the inverse

Comment: [for the new version of the question] This direction is not correct.  Consider $f$ constant.  The converse direction is correct.

Comment: Just switch the letters "a" and "b".

Comment: The question in the body doesn't match the one in the title.

Comment: @JairTaylor the question in the body is the contraposition of the one in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can exchange $a$ and $b$ to prove it.
For each $a$ and each $b$, $a \geq b \Longrightarrow b \leq a \Longrightarrow f(b) \leq f(a)$.